# XML Validation Error - Content model of element ExecutionResult disallows element Module at this position

Tags: xml, xml-validation

I am new to XML and am trying to create an XML report. I get the error *Content model of element ExecutionResult disallows element Module at this position.* for the module tags and same goes for the Step tag as well. I am not sure what the error is.

```
<ExecutionResult>
<Script_Name>abc</Script_Name>
<Tester_Name>poiuytrewwq</Tester_Name>
<Execution_Date>12 June 2015</Execution_Date>
<ExecutionStartTime>10:15:36:01AM</ExecutionStartTime>
<ExecutionEndTime>10:20:36:01AM</ExecutionEndTime>
<ExecutionTimeTaken>0:5:00</ExecutionTimeTaken>
<Final_Status>FAIL</Final_Status>
<Module>CreatePO
    <Step>
        <SlNo>1</SlNo>
        <Step_Name>xyz</Step_Name>
        <Result>Pass</Result>
        <Time_Taken>1.1 Sec</Time_Taken>
        <ScreenShot> </ScreenShot>
    </Step>
</Module>
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Where is your XML schema?

Comment: The error says, that the tag `<Module>` in not allowed at the current position within `<ExecutionResult>`.

Comment: Thx a lot guys, figured out the issue. The issue was with the DTD file. Adding in the corrected file

Comment: Thx a lot guys. Figured out the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thx a lot. Figured out the issue. The error was in the DTD file and also made a few changes to my XML.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
            <!DOCTYPE Result SYSTEM "report.dtd">
            <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="abc.xsl" ?>
            <Result>
                <ExecutionResult>
                    <Script_Name>abc</Script_Name>
                    <Tester_Name>poiuytrewwq</Tester_Name>
                    <Execution_Date>12 June 2015</Execution_Date>
                    <ExecutionStartTime>10:15:36:01AM</ExecutionStartTime>
                    <ExecutionEndTime>10:20:36:01AM</ExecutionEndTime>
                    <ExecutionTimeTaken>0:5:00</ExecutionTimeTaken>
                    <Final_Status>FAIL</Final_Status>
                </ExecutionResult>
                <Module>
                    <Module_Name>Open Po </Module_Name>
                    <Step>
                        <SlNo>1</SlNo>
                        <Step_Name>xyz</Step_Name>
                        <Status>Pass</Status>
                        <Time_Taken>1.1 Sec</Time_Taken>
                        <InputValue>098</InputValue>
                        <Message>pass</Message>
                        <ScreenShot>No</ScreenShot>
                    </Step>
                    <Step>
                        <SlNo>2</SlNo>
                        <Step_Name>pqr</Step_Name>
                        <Status>Fail</Status>
                        <Time_Taken>1.2 Sec</Time_Taken>
                        <InputValue>098</InputValue>
                        <Message>pass</Message>
                        <ScreenShot>location</ScreenShot>
                    </Step>
                </Module>
                <Module>
                    <Module_Name>EditPO</Module_Name>
                    <Step>
                        <SlNo>3</SlNo>
                        <Step_Name>123</Step_Name>
                        <Status>Pass</Status>
                        <Time_Taken>1.1 Sec</Time_Taken>
                        <InputValue>098</InputValue>
                        <Message>pass</Message>
                        <ScreenShot>No</ScreenShot>
                    </Step>
                    <Step>
                        <SlNo>4</SlNo>
                        <Step_Name>456</Step_Name>
                        <Status>Fail</Status>
                        <Time_Taken>1.2 Sec</Time_Taken>
                        <InputValue>098</InputValue>
                        <Message>pass</Message>
                        <ScreenShot>location</ScreenShot>
                    </Step>
                </Module>
            </Result>
```

Below id the DTD file that I have created.

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <!ELEMENT Result (ExecutionResult,Module+)>
                <!ELEMENT ExecutionResult (Script_Name,Tester_Name,Execution_Date,ExecutionStartTime,ExecutionEndTime,ExecutionTimeTaken,Final_Status)>
                <!ELEMENT Module (Module_Name,Step+)>
                <!ELEMENT Step (SlNo,Step_Name,Status,Time_Taken,InputValue,Message,ScreenShot)>
                <!ELEMENT Script_Name (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT Tester_Name (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT Execution_Date (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT ExecutionStartTime (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT ExecutionEndTime (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT ExecutionTimeTaken (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT Module_Name (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT Final_Status (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT SlNo (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT Step_Name (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT Status (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT Time_Taken (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT InputValue (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT Message (#PCDATA)>
                <!ELEMENT ScreenShot (#PCDATA)>
```

Now only thing left is to add in a XSL file for this and i should be good to go.